# simple Post WebApi node.js Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing small  post WebAPI with node.js to take user data name and number and if i have too much users for this web API i get the below error
**node.js Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.post('/', function(req, res){
 
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: '*****',
        password: '******',
        server: '********', 
  port: '****',
        database: '*****' 
    };
 
     sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
  
   request.input('UserName', req.query.Name);
   request.input('UserNomber', req.query.Number);
 
   
           
        // query to the database and get the records
  
   request.execute('SP_InsertUserData', function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
   
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordsets));
   sql.close();
        });
  
  
    console.log(req.query.name);
 
    });
 
 
   

});



var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to create pool connection rather than connecting sql directly.

```
var config = {
        user: '*****',
        password: '******',
        server: '********', 
        port: '****',
        database: '*****' 
    };

new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
 var request = new sql.Request(pool);

     request.input('UserName', req.query.Name);
     request.input('UserNomber', req.query.Number);



    // query to the database and get the records

     request.execute('SP_InsertUserData', function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({ message: "${err}"})
          sql.close();
        }
        else {
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          res.status(200).json(recordsets);
          sql.close();
        }
    });
});
```

**Note**

```
var request = new sql.Request(/* [pool or transaction] */)
```

If you omit pool/transaction argument, global pool is used instead.

I hope this will help you. If you have any doubts or suggestion let me know.